# How to determine character encoding of an XML file

Tags: xml, character-encoding, notepad++

I have the following XML file that I need to edit with a text editor like Notepad++ however I am unable to determine the correct encoding the file uses after testing all of the common encoding options available in Notepad++.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XD4NeOpcJ-crPufUaXxnlnzHGPBNDT8D

I can confirm that the file is not corrupt at least in the respect that it can be successfully read by two programs (Skyrim LE and JFF) that utilize the file.

Also, although JFF can open the file and read its contents correctly, after saving any changes made with JFF, the updated file is no longer read correctly in Skyrim.

Comment: There is [libchardet by Mozilla](https://github.com/Joungkyun/libchardet), the char set detector of Firefox. Or you can simply open this file in Firefox and then _Right-Click_ + _View Page-Info_.

Comment: I did previously test with Firefox, but it has trouble with this file (no xml information displayed and is stuck loading), and the text encoding is determined as UTF-8.  Are you able to look at the file and let me know if there is something I am missing?

Comment: The file that you have linked to does not appear to contain xml.  If it was xml, the prolog should declare the encoding if it isn't UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: The file does contain valid XML markup since JFF and Skyrim are able to read it, along with valid XML files, but the issue here is that it appears to use some uncommon character encoding for the markup that cannot be easily determined, or is partially corrupted such that editors like Notepad++ are unable to determine the encoding using expected formatting rules.